# Azure Availability Test missing historical data

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Under Azure's Application Insights there are basic Availability test that show site uptime.

Over the last several weeks (all of 2024?) the view for 3 days, 7 days and "Custom" has stopped showing any data. Which is odd because the 30 day view works fine.

The 3 days, 7 days and "Custom" options:

[image: Date Time selector]

What 3 days, 7 days and "Custom" now shows:
[image: Azure Application Insights Availability test with no data]

What it used to show (for years with out any change on our part):
[image: Azure Application Insights Availability test with data]

We haven't changed anything on our side, and with the 30 day view working I feel like this could be a Microsoft issue. However I could find no mention of this online and it has been several weeks like this now.

Any way I can force this data to surface or are we just out of luck?

Comment: It means your tests are not running. Can you double check that they are not in disabled state? If they are not - the best approach is to open a support ticket. Do you have a support plan?

Comment: They are running. I can see data for 24 hours and 30 days - just nothing in-between.

Comment: If you go to `Metrics` (resource menu), switch namespace to `Application Insights standard metrics`, select `Availability`, switch to 30 days - what do you see?

Comment: And same for 3 days, 7 days and 24 hours.

Comment: If you can successfully see data within last 24 hours, then on within last 30 days (without gaps) but 3-day/7-day don't show anything - then it is definitely on Azure - the best way to move forward is to open support ticket.

Comment: @ZakiMa I do see data via the Metrics view for 7 days!

Comment: So, in Metrics you can see Availability metric (ensure that you switched to standard metrics - otherwise that graph is built using logs) but not in Availability UX? This is strange, they are powered by the same metric. Re: support - do you think you can file a support ticket? Feel free to to point me to it via <my SO alias> @ <microsoft.com>

Comment: Thanks @ZakiMa! I have raised a support ticket with MS. A little tricky as we are only on a Basic Support Plan. I raised it as a billing issue as the "technical" category is not available to me :;

Comment: If you send its id to me then my team will be able to take a look (assuming that we have access to not "technical" category). And yes, it doesn't repro on our availability tests.

Comment: thank you (feel free to delete the comment with case number). Looking.

Comment: It turns out that this UX is powered by two different sources. 24-hour & 30-day use metrics but other time ranges fall back to logs (reasoning is convoluted and around the granularity we want to visualize vs. number of time series available at that granularity). Logs should have everything, so, using metrics is just an optimization for this particular experience (it is faster to query metrics than compute them based on logs).

Comment: Our current hypothesis is that something happened with permissions to underlying Log Analytics Workspace. If you go to `Logs` resource menu - what does the following query return? 

`availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| make-series count() default=0 on timestamp in range(ago(30d), now(), 1d)
| render timechart `

Comment: At first I got zero results for that query. Then I changed the Workspace to out Prod log analytics (away from the default one) and new data started coming in. This may have fixed it. The 7 day view now shows some data (just the last hour, but there is data).

Comment: Great! Was another workspace deleted?

Comment: It was set to a Workspace I don't believe we (intentionally) setup, DefaultWorkspace-{guid}-EAU. I did  not deleted it, just change the App Insight to point to our Prod instance.

Comment: That Workspace should have worked just fine. Would it be possible to check whether it exists or not? If it does exist - do you see data there (schema is a bit different, table name is called `AppAvailabilityResults`). This will help us to understand what happened and come up with better experience (which would at least explain the problem). Thank you! If it is easier - feel free to send details to my SO alias at microsoft.com.